# typescript Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type X can't be used to index type Y

Tags: typescript

Any help to this would be appreciated

```
interface Error {
  messages: string[];
    entity: 'test' | null;
}

interface GroupedErrors {
  [errorGroup: string]: Error['messages'] | Error[];
}

interface UngroupedErrors {
  ungrouped: Error[];
}

type GroupErrors = GroupedErrors | UngroupedErrors | {};

interface Preset {
  errors: Error[];
}

export function groupPresetErrors(preset: Preset): GroupErrors {
  return preset.errors.reduce<GroupErrors>((acc, error) => {
    if (error.entity === 'test') {
      return {
        ...acc,
        ['test']: acc['test']
          ? [...acc['test'], ...error.messages]
          : error.messages,
      };
    }

    return {
      ...acc,
      ['ungrouped']: acc['ungrouped'] ? [...acc['ungrouped'], error] : [error],
    };
  }, {});
}
```

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"test"' can't be used to index type 'GroupErrors'.
Property 'test' does not exist on type 'GroupErrors'.**

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKJSgeysg3gKGWQFsIBnMuAc3IC5kywpQqBtAXQG5CjkJxgYAJ70A5JEajkAH2QgArgBtF3AL758oSLEQoA4lnkAHCABN0WKGTw9W0SwczH6jZiCrt6F7K1GkK1OSi7DJoGD5c+Oqa4NDwSMgAqu6GJubhVjZE8ilOaV4ZHGoawibIjsbemQC85almVdayyVT16ZZNeKrcMdrxKAAKUOQQYFl8GWQFlkVRGhAAHkbYYzA5CGDAmCDIrXlDI2CNABRGw2Sj9AcXYACU9BVGjePDYPJQO2eHAHT22GTfYameRIAA8j0aAD5jsdEAgADQTSy3ZDVSHjIjAGDIY5-KC-ATCVHVWrichgUQogi8Xivd47ak03jfFlw+E8JnIXwSCmeZBw7nk4IcznIAD8XJZ3wFZMk7ERUrx338lBoZHYIs59CVKsCZHZnO6IvUNLpH35CAQ3CIqkRuFUtzUQA)

Comment: The error is correct; the type of your accumulator `GroupErrors` is not known to have a `test` property, so you can't safely access it.  Perhaps you want your accumulator to be of type `GroupedErrors` instead, or something even more specific like `{[k: string]: string[]}`, as in [this fix](https://tsplay.dev/wgLXvN)?  Since your question is just some code and an error message, it's hard for me to be sure what exactly the intent is here.  If my suggested fix above doesn't work for you, could you elaborate?  Otherwise I'm happy to write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Why does iti error if `GroupErrors` can be `GroupedErrors` which accepts any string key (through `[errorGroup: string]`?

Comment: `GroupErrors` is a union type, and you can only safely access properties of a union that are known to be present in *all* members of the union.  Since `test` is not known to be present in `{}`, you can't access the `test` property of `GroupErrors`.  So, how should we proceed here?  Could you edit the text of the question to describe what your problem is and what sort of help you need?  Or can I assume that the above fix will work for you and just make an answer with that?

Comment: @jcalz I get that it'a union type, but shouldn't the tenary of `acc['test'] ? ` address that?

Comment: @jcalz I need `groupPresetErrors` to be able to return `GroupErrors` because it can return `{}`

Comment: I feel like these questions, if you need them answered, should be present in the text of your post.

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the text and the code as your solution works, but I need it work with the new code I added for `['ungrouped']: acc['ungrouped'] ? [...acc['ungrouped'], error] : [error]`

Comment: So then does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkjMlm) work for you?  If the compiler doesn't know whether an object has a certain property you can't just index into it with the property, but you can [use the `in` operator as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).